# install openscad fails on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

Tanks for the LANGUAGE=en hint!

```
> LANGUAGE=en sudo apt-get install openscad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblinear1 : Depends: libblas3 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libblas.so.3 or
                       libatlas3-base but it is not going to be installed
 openscad : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-program-options1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-regex1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-thread1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcgal10 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libopencsg1 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: openscad-mcad but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is openscad not supported any more?

Comment: Try again with `LANGUAGE=en sudo apt-get install openscad`, edit your question and past the new result.

Comment: Yes, what Lucio said, but short answer. Some of the dependencies are different versions than expected.

Comment: @geoffmcc: That doesn't help me any further!?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this question while searching details on OpenSCAD installation. 
On the developer's site (where you can find the latest version), for Ubuntu 14.04, it is specified:

> $ **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openscad/releases**
>   (and then) 
>   $ **sudo apt-get install openscad**

- I've just installed it this way and now begun drawing, discovering how it works (fine until now:) ).

Here is the link for other possible useful info> http://www.openscad.org/downloads.html#linux

Comment: Doesn't have a manual due to some licence issue with the QCAD CE; developer's recommendation for info> http://librecad.org/cms/home/get-help.html ; good results with an Internet search